# Program returns to first function instead of the next function

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++

Ok so I am finishing a program for a bookstore. However, when running my code it works but
     but not properly. First it displays the mainmenu function where the user chooses from 4
     options, enters the number and displays the next function chosen. When trying to choose
     from the second function the program returns to the first function and starts over again.
     Ex. mainmenu()-->invmenu()(selects addBook() function from invmenu())-->but instead it
     returns to mainmenu(). I do not know why is this happening. I tried each part by separated
     and they worked fine.

```
This is my code so far
//The main menu displays a window where the user can 
//choose which one module to run or exit the program
//Luis Fierro
//11-8-2014

#include "mainmenu.h"


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//prototypes
void mMenu();
void cashier();
void invmenu();
void report();
void bookInfo();

//inventory function prototypes
void lookUpBook();
void addBook();
void editBook();
void deleteBook();



 int main()
 {
 mMenu();
 }

 void mMenu()
 {

    int choice;

    do{
        //display the menu and get a choice
        cout << "\t\t\tSerendipity Booksellers\n" << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\t\tMain Menu\n\n" << endl;
        cout << "1. Cashier Module\n" << endl;
        cout << "2. Inventory Database Module\n" << endl;
        cout << "3. Report Module\n" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit \n\n" << endl;

        cout << "Enter Your Choice: \n" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

      //make sure numbers are not out of the range
        while (choice <= 0 || choice > 4)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number in the range 1-4 " << endl;

            cout << "Enter Your Choice: \n" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        }

        //respond to the user's selection
        switch (choice){
        case 1: cashier();
            break;
        case 2: invmenu();
            break;
        case 3: report();
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Bye, bye!!!" << endl;
            break;
        }

    } while (choice != 4);

    system("Pause");


 }
//function cashier
 void cashier()
 {
 //initialize variables
    int option;
    string date;
    int bQuantity;
    string isbn;
    string bTitle;
    float bPrice;
    double total = 0.0;
    double tax = 0;
    double subtotal = 0.0;

    //constant 
    const double YES_OPTION = 1,
        NO_OPTION = 2;

    //ask the user
    cout << "What is the date(MM/DD/YY): " << endl;
    cin >> date;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Number of books purchased: " << endl;
    cin >> bQuantity;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "ISBN number: " << endl;
    cin >> isbn;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    Court << "Title of book: " << end;
    cin >> bTitle;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Cost of book: " << endl;
    cin >> bPrice;
    cout << " \n\n" << endl;

    //display information to the user
    cout << "Serendipity Booksellers\n" << endl;
    cout << "\tCashier Module\n\n" << endl;
    cout << "Date: " << date << " \n" << endl;
    cout << "Quantity of Book " << bQuantity << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "ISBN " << isbn << " \n" << endl;
    cout << "Title: " << bTitle << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Price: $" << bPrice << "\n\n\n" << endl;

    //calculations
    subtotal = (bQuantity*bPrice);

    tax = (bQuantity*bPrice)*0.06;

    total = subtotal + tax;

    //display final window with all the info
    cout << "Serendipity Book Sellers\n\n " << endl;
    cout << "Date: " << date << endl;
    cout << "\nQty      ISBN        Title       Price       Total\n\n" << endl;
    cout << "________________________________________________________\n\n\n" << endl;
    cout << " " << bQuantity << " \t\t" << isbn << "\t" << bTitle << "\t\t$" << bPrice <<     "\t\t$" << subtotal << endl;
    cout << "       \n\n\tSubtotal: " << "\t\t\t\t\t\t$" << subtotal << endl;
    cout << "           \n\tTax: " << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$" << tax << endl;
    cout << "           \n\tTotal: " << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$" << total << endl;

    cout << "\n\nThank You for Shopping at Serendipity!\n\n" << endl;


    //ask user if needs another transaction
    cout << "\t\tAnother transaction?" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t1. Yes" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t2. No\n" << endl;
    cin >> option;

    if (option == YES_OPTION)
    {
        cashier();
    }
    else if (option == NO_OPTION)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease come again!!" << endl;
    }


    cin.get();

   }
 //second menu
 void invmenu()

 {
   //initialize variable
    int choice1;

    do {//display the menu
        cout << "\t\t\tSerendipity Booksellers\n" << endl;

        cout << "\t\t\tInventory Database\n" << endl;

        cout << "\n\t\t\t1. Look Up a Book" << endl;

        cout << "\n\t\t\t2. Add a Book" << endl;

        cout << "\n\t\t\t3. Edit a Book's Record" << endl;

        cout << "\n\t\t\t4. Delete a Book" << endl;

        cout << "\n\t\t\t5. Return to the main menu" << endl;

        cout << "\n\t\t\tEnter Your Choice: \n " << endl;

        cout << "Enter Your Choice: \n" << endl;
        cin >> choice1;

       //make sure numbers are not out of range
        while (choice1 <= 0 || choice1 > 5)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number in the range 1-5 " << endl;

            cout << "Enter Your Choice: \n" << endl;
            cin >> choice1;
        }


        //Respond to the user's selection
        switch (choice1){
        case 1: lookUpBook();
            break;
        case 2: addBook();
            break;
        case 3: editBook();
            break;
        case 4: deleteBook();
            break;
        case 5: mMenu();
            break;
        }

    } while (choice1 = !5);
    cin.get();


 }
 //last functions for the invmenu
 void lookUpBook ()
 {

    cout << "You selected look up a book" << endl;
 }

 void addBook()
 {

    cout << "You selected add a book" << endl;
 }

 void editBook()
 {
    cout << "You selected edit a book" << endl;
 }

 void deleteBook()
 {
    cout << "You selected delete a book" << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: hint: look into what `choice1 = !5` does.

Answer (score 1):

As SleuthEye points out, your loop condition `choice1 = !5` is causing `invmenu` to end its loop no matter what the user does.  I would suggest that you intend this:

```
choice1 != 5
```

Comment: thanks! guys I actually broke the whole thing into parts and try each one with the main function and then I added all together and now it is working correctly. I appreciate everybody's advise.